# How to call a parameter inside a PIVOT statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, pivot

I need to parameterize my query so that it takes by FM inside the IN PIVOT the value passed as a parameter:`enter code here`

This is working:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Head]
    @fiscalYear int,
    @fiscalMonth int 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT tblrB.Company, tblrB.FM, tblrB.Amount 
         FROM tblrB 
         WHERE tblrB.FY = @fiscalYear 
           AND tblrB.FM = @fiscalMonth 
         GROUP BY tblrB.CompanyCd, tblrB.Cd, tblrB.FM, tblrB.Amount) t 
    PIVOT 
        (SUM(Amount) FOR FM IN ([12]) --12 AS EXAMPLE) p;
```

But not this is not:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Head]
    @fiscalYear int,
    @fiscalMonth int 
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        (SELECT tblrB.Company, tblrB.FM, tblrB.Amount
         FROM tblrB 
         WHERE tblrB.FY = @fiscalYear AND tblrB.FM = @fiscalMonth 
         GROUP BY tblrB.Company, tblrB.Cd, tblrB.FM, tblrB.Amount) t 
    PIVOT 
        (SUM(Amount) FOR FM IN ([@fiscalMonth ])) p;
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Why is there a `GROUP BY` inside `t` at all, why does its column list not match the `SELECT` list, and why would it ever include `FM`/`Amount`? It can't possibly be working as written.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need dynamic SQL for this:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
  SELECT * FROM 
  (
    SELECT tblrB.Company, tblrB.FM, tblrB.Amount
      FROM dbo.tblrB 
      WHERE tblrB.FY = @fy AND tblrB.FM = @fm
  ) AS t 
  PIVOT 
  (
    SUM(Amount) FOR FM IN (' + QUOTENAME(@fiscalMonth) + N')
  ) AS p;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@fy int, @fm int', @fiscalYear, @fiscalMonth;
```

Though if you're only returning one column I don't see the need for a `PIVOT` at all; this seems like a standard `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Company, Amount = SUM(Amount)
  FROM dbo.tblrB
  WHERE tblrB.FY = @fiscalYear AND tblrB.FM = @fiscalMonth
  GROUP BY Company;
```

If the point of the `PIVOT` was to have a dynamically-named column header, you could have done this at the presentation layer (have whatever is *rendering* the results print out the month number it must have known when it called the procedure), but even if you absolutely must have it come from SQL Server, it's easier with `GROUP BY` than `PIVOT` (at least IMHO):

```
DECLARE @sql2 nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT Company, ' 
  + QUOTENAME(@fiscalMonth) + N' = SUM(Amount)
    FROM dbo.tblrB
    WHERE tblrB.FY = @fy AND tblrB.FM = @fm
    GROUP BY Company;';
    
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql2, N'@fy int, @fm int', @fiscalYear, @fiscalMonth;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2baf368c25f6c5a129284ac959d0795e)